# NPM Windows Upgrade Stuck on Arrow Key Selection

Tags: windows, npm

The correct way to upgrade npm on Windows appears to be running the following in an elevated command line:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force
npm install -g npm-windows-upgrade
npm-windows-upgrade
```

However, for me, on Windows 10, both in cmd and PowerShell, `npm-windows-upgrade` asks to select the upgrade version like so:

> Which version do you want to install? (Use arrow keys)

Unfortunately, no key works: not the arrow keys, not the numpad arrow keys, and not any other plausible option (like numbers). How do I get around this, or select the relevant version?

Answer (score 2):

A workaround I have found is to specify the upgrade version in advance with the `npm-version` parameter. Therefore first one can run `npm-windows-upgrade` to get a list of available versions.

Then copy whatever version to a new PowerShell window, for example:

```
npm-windows-upgrade --npm-version 6.10.2
```

or:

```
npm-windows-upgrade --npm-version latest
```